# Error accessing Server Status of GeoServer

Tags: geoserver

I have installed GeoServer 2.17, using openJDK 11. When access the Server Status page, form aside menu on the main page after login, return a error below:

[Link to full stack trace in text file.](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1GM2sNIaI5A2tftcyKCoupcDa-Bbtybcj/view?usp=sharing)

Comment: Works for me with GeoServer 2.17.1 on Windows with AdoptOpenJDK: 11.0.5 (OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM). We must have somehow different installation but I can't say what it could be.

Comment: I've recently installed geoserver 2.17.2 on my computer and it works fine. Geoserver 2.17.x is available only in `.war` and `binary` format. If you're installing binary file, you need to set **DATA_DIR** and **GEOSERVER_HOME** variable on environment variable.

Comment: @ArashMadadi I did install with Platform Independent Binary methos (file .zip) and make the set up following the documentation. Everything works fine, exception of Status Server option at menu.

Comment: @user30184 My installation is under Linux distro by Platform Independent Binary methos (file .zip).

Comment: It seems you cut the stack trace short, can you include the full one?

Comment: @AndreaAime I did provide a link to a text file containing full stack trace, due characters limit of question.

Comment: Following the link I get a 404

Comment: @AndreaAime Add a new link.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not 100% sure, but believe it's related to the environment you're working in. Seens similar problems with headless docker images, was due to two bits:

- Java not being told it's running in a headless environment (`java.awt.headless` was not set, e.g. `-Djava.awt.headless=true` as part of the command line starting the Java process)
- An package not always installed in Ubuntu server  actually required by Java, e.g., see this discussion: https://github.com/AdoptOpenJDK/openjdk-build/issues/693, in this case the solution would be to install fontconfig `sudo apt-get install fontconfig`

Comment: Thank Andrea, my environment is GeoServer installed on Ubuntu 18.04, as systemd unit process, usign openJDK 11, is not a docker container, but even though I did try to add -Djava.awt.headless=true to JAVA-OPTS comand to start process but I got the same error.